# Guest OS crashes after installing VMware Tools

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I've enabled VT-d in BIOS setting, and run VMware Workstation as root. Everything went well before installing VMware Tools into it. After installing VMware Tools, the guest OS (Windows XP and 7) was stuck right after logo loading screen. There were neither blue screen nor error messages, but the CPU usage rose to 100 percent on a single core. It is really weird because this virtual machine can be run on another computer of mine which also run host OS as Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

How to solve this? Any hints are appreciated.

VMware Workstation 10.0.4 build-2249910 on Intel i7-4790k and Gigabyte Z97M-D3H.

Comment: WAY more info needed.  for ex.   VMWS version (Cpu and drive type /topology / even basic configs of VM Guests), also does the Host have sufficient h/w to support this?

Comment: Solved. Just for somebody who may face the same problem like me, the only solution is to upgrade your VMware Workstation to version 11.1 or later.